# Save array element on input blur

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a table filled with elements of an `Array`, say `phases: Phase[];`.

When my user clicks on a row of my table, he is able to edit its content via inputs, when any input blurs (loses focus) I wish to save that new information for that specific element in our array.

I am looking for a clean way to do it, here's how I have been trying so far:

```
<!-- Table rows -->
<tr *ngFor="let phase of phases ; let i = index" [attr.data-index]="i">
   <input value="{{phase.name}}" (blur)="savePhase(phase, i)">  
   <input value="{{phase.milestone}}" (blur)="savePhase(phase, i)">
</tr>
```

Where `savePhase(phase, index)` should save our element with its new value. But here's where I can't find a solution, upon blur, my method **does get called but the value of `phase` contains the old ones.**

How may I let me method know: what specific value is to be changed (name, milestone etc.) without passing its new value and its name?

If I were to do the following: `savePhase(phase, index, inputName, inputValue)` my method wouldn't be clean, and maintenance would be hellish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is ngModel

```
<tr *ngFor="let phase of phases ; let i = index" [attr.data-index]="i">
   <input [ngModel]="phase.name" (blur)="savePhase(phase, i)">  
   <input [ngModel]="phase.milestone" (blur)="savePhase(phase, i)">
</tr>
```